# Got a jury summon last year, forgot about it, just remembered

Tags: criminal-law

What should I do? I would like to serve on a jury if I can.

Ive passed 2 background checks since the jury duty notice. If i recall correctly the notice misspelled my name.

Comment: In what jurisdiction?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, the court can punish you for not responding to the summons; it is most likely that you won't actually be cited. I understand that non-appearance rates in parts of California are as high as 1/3 of the time, in which case a judge might decide to crack down on those who ignore notices. It is extremely unlikely that you would be assigned to a blacklist for failing to appear.

You can't volunteer for federal jury duty. You can [volunteer in New York](https://www.nycourts.gov/COURTS/10JD/nassau/cojask.shtml), but not in [Washington state](https://www.kingcounty.gov/courts/superior-court/juror-information/FAQ.aspx) or [California](http://www.lacourt.org/division/jury/JR0016.aspx). States vary as to where they get the list of names, for example from voter's lists (to guarantee that the person is a citizen), or from driver's license records (in which case a non-citizen may be called, and has to pay attention to the line on the form where you swear that you are a citizen). [Florida has a provision](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0000-0099/0040/Sections/0040.011.html) whereby you can get your name added to the list in case you aren't registered to vote and don't have a license. You can check the laws of your state to see if there is a mechanism for adding yourself to the list, if you aren't already on it.

Comment: I would suspect that in most jurisdictions, someone who shows up with an old summons and says "I am sorry, I completely forgot about this" will just be scheduled for a jury pool.  Maybe some places would impose a small slap-on-the-wrist fine, but my interactions with jury systems in New York suggest that it is unlikely here.

Comment: You might want to look in to how jury duty works where you are. For example, I was summoned, and would have had to call an automated phone number the night before I was to appear to see if I was really needed. You might have lucked out and been among those who didn't have to appear anyway.